# Файловая система для хранения большого кол-ва файлов

Tags: linux, администрирование, файловая-система, centos7

Категорически приветствую! Существует ТЗ: Выбрать ФС для хранения ~5млн бинарных файлов размером от 10КБ до 10МБ. Общий размер на данный момент ~25ТБ. Это количество будет постоянно увеличиваться. Все файлы будут рассортированы по директориям в следующем порядке: Если имя файла `6a5ebae5` то рекурсивно будут созданы директории `6a/5e/ba/e5` куда и разместится файл.

Необходима ФС наиболее выгодная по доступу/чтению/записи. В данный момент предполагается использование `xfs` просто потому что.

P.S. При ответе важно именно **техническое обоснование** с указанием источника. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: См. [What is the most high-performance Linux filesystem for storing a lot of small files (HDD, not SSD)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-is-the-most-high-performance-linux-filesystem-for-storing-a-lot-of-small-fi).

Comment: Отказоустойчивость, репликация, сетевой доступ - нужны?

Comment: @Akina спасибо, обязательно прочитаю! Сам, почему-то, не нагуглировал :(

Comment: @gbg нет, это всё уже есть. Отказоустойчивость обеспечивает raid10 (точно не помню, сейчас нет возможности посмотреть) на дисковой полке. Сетевой доступ через приложение которое будет заниматься записью/чтением.

Comment: Я бы в такой ситуации отказался от ФС в пользу СУБД.

Comment: добавлю, что xfs вместо, скажем, ext4 стоило бы использовать, если бы все файлы были в одном каталоге... а в данном случае и если в ТЗ нет требований по нагрузке, то можно использовать любую болей-менее современную ФС — отличий под умеренной нагрузкой заметно не будет...

Comment: @gbg а я в такой ситуации отказался от субд mongo, потому что уже 100500 шард где растёт фрагментирование с каждым днём. Выбор сделан в пользу хранения просто в ФС.

Comment: Можно ещё посмотреть в сторону `JFS`.